# Is this the right paradigm for a preemptive, exclusive function in a multithreading environment?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am implementing a preemptive, exclusive function in a multithreaded  environment, where if a cancel request occurs even when the function is not running, when the function does run, it knows about this cancel request and does not run. I came across various different ways to do this in C# using ManualResetEvent and the like(something like the answer to this question [Synchronizing a Timers.Timer elapsed method when stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810498/synchronizing-a-timers-timer-elapsed-method-when-stopping)), however I was wondering if something as simple as what I am doing in the code below would suffice. Are there any inadvertent bugs that I am introducing here?

```
bool cancel = false;
bool running = false;
object Lock = new object();
void PremptiveExclusiveFunction() {
  lock(Lock) {
    if(running)
      return;
    running = true;
  }

  for(int i=0; i < numIter; i++) {
    lock(Lock) {
      if(cancel) {
       cancel = false;
       running = false;
       return;
      }
    }

    // iteration code
  }

  lock(Lock) {
   running = false;
  } 
}

void Stop() {
  lock(Lock) {
    cancel = true;
  }
}
```

As far as I know, this seems to handle my 3 requirements: 
1. ability to preempt 
2. exclusivity in time, where this only copy of this function can be running 
3. a cancel request not being lost because Stop is called before PreemptiveExclusiveFunction

I'd be grateful if more experienced minds could point out if I am indeed missing something.

Comment: Exceptions inside your for-loop might end the function without resetting "running" to false.

Comment: Hi @ThomasB., thanks for your comment. That is a great catch. I had not thought of that. Do you think there's any other problem with the code?

Comment: There is so much locking. A huge number of threads trying to enter the function could slow down the one thread actually executing the loop, because they compete for the same lock. And the access to "cancel" is different from the access to the function itself and should be secured by different mechanism and not the same lock. (As one answer proposes, cancel could be a volatile field)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ThomasB. I see what you mean about a different mechanism for cancel and access to the function. I only used the same lock because after checking if the _cancel_ flag has been set inside the _for_ loop, if I do have to cancel, I also set the _running_ flag to _false_, which controls access to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entire function body can be locked to eliminate the `running` boolean:

```
object @lock = new object();

volatile bool cancel = false;

void Function () {
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(@lock))
        return;
    try {

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (cancel) {
                cancel = false;
                return;
            }

            // code
        }

    } finally {
        Monitor.Exit(@lock);
    }
}

void Stop () {
    cancel = true;
}
```

+ Notice the `volatile` keyword:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x13ttww7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hi @poopysprint, thanks for your answer. This is a great way to do the same thing. I was just wondering though if there was anything that could go wrong in my implementation of it, apart from what the comment above points out. Thanks! In any case, I will accept your answer as the answer.

Comment: Put locks everywhere and scratch your head wondering if anything can go wrong, aww. Pencil usually helps! I don't see problems except those mentioned.

Comment: Well, a guy's gotta learn! And until such epiphany hits, can you blame him for trying!? Thanks for your answer! Appreciate it.