# .Net: how to wait until System.Timers.Timer stops

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a `System.Timers.Timer` instance created in the main thread. Now I call `timer.Stop()` to try to terminate that time and want to wait until the timer is really terminated. How could I do that?

Is there any similar method like `System.Threading.Thread.Join()`?

Here are some codes

```
//the main thread:
var aTimer = New Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += SomeTimerTask;
aTimer.AutoReset = True;
aTimer.Start();

//some other logic...

//stop that timer:
aTimer.Stop();

//now I need to wait until that timer is really stopped,
//but I cannot touch the method SomeTimerTask().
//so I need something like System.Threading.Thread.Join()...
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx has a code sample which shows how to avoid this exact issue.

Comment: What you'd *really* want to ensure that the Elapsed event is not going to run again.  You can't get such a guarantee, [you'll have to check](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810724/17034) in your event handler.  Do consider System.Threading.Timer instead, its Dispose(WaitHandle) overload provides a guarantee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of a ResetEvents which are wait handles which can block a thread until you set the state to signaled:

```
class TimerAndWait
{
    private ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += SomeTimerTask;
        aTimer.Elapsed += ATimer_Elapsed;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Start();

        // Do something else

        resetEvent.WaitOne(); // This blocks the thread until resetEvent is set
        resetEvent.Close();
        aTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        resetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

If you want a async/task-based solution you have to use the [ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/02x3daw5(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

The Timer does not fire up the `Elapsed` when you call stop as you can read in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Stop()`-Method:

> Stops raising the Elapsed event by setting Enabled to false.

The **Elapsed**-Event is only triggered when the `Timer`s `Enabled`-Property is set to `true` and the given `Interval` (which you have to set) is elapsed (this can happen multiple times).

So if you stop your Timer before the Interval is elapsed, you might have to trigger your code in some other way.